# Dois formulários, uma view, um relacionamento 1-N, como eu posso pegar o id do 1º form e usa-lá como FK no 2º form (atribuindo-a a model.FIELD)

Tags: python, django

Antes de tudo, apenas um aviso, estou postando apenas porque nenhum dos tópicos aqui na pilha me ajudou, nem mesmo as sugestões relacionadas quando nomeei este tópico ...
Sou novo no django, estou trabalhando na abertura de um ticket de suporte, estou lutando com esse problema há dois dias.

É possível atribuir um valor ao campo definido em model.py por view.py? Meu problema é ter duas classes de modelo, dois formulários com relacionamento um-para-muitos, que são renderizados na mesma página e devem ser salvos ao clicar em um botão.

***Meu model.py***

```
class TicketStatus(models.TextChoices):
    TO_DO = 'Open'
    DONE = 'Closed'
    
class Ticket(models.Model):
    objects = None
    id = models.BigAutoField(auto_created=True, primary_key=True, serialize=False, verbose_name='ID')
    id_author = models.ForeignKey(User, null=False, blank=False, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField('Created at', auto_now_add=True)
    status = models.CharField(max_length=10, choices=TicketStatus.choices, default=TicketStatus.TO_DO)

class MessageTicket(models.Model):
    objects = None
    created_at = models.DateTimeField('Created at', auto_now_add=True)
    ticket_id = models.ForeignKey(Ticket, null=False, blank=False, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING, related_name='messages') #meu problema está aqui
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, null=False, blank=False, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
    content = models.TextField(null=True, default='')
```

O ponto aqui é que 'ticket_id' na classe 'MessageTicket' deve receber o 'id' do último 'Ticket' salvo(o 'ultimo' é aquele que será salvo no momento), mas como ambos são salvos ao mesmo tempo não consigo puxar o último 'id' do 'Ticket'.

***Meu view.py:***

```
formTicket = TicketForm(request.POST)
if formTicket.is_valid():
    formTicket.save()
    help = Ticket.objects.latest('pk').pk
    print(help) #'debug' para eu ver se está pegando o valor do último pk, sim está
    formMessage = MesTicketForm(request.POST)
    if formMessage.is_valid():
        #O que preciso colocar aqui para que o 'ticket_id' di 'messageTicket' (modelo)
        #receba o 'id' do 'Ticket', tudo que tentei me retorna o erro que 'ticket_id'            
        #não pode ser nulo

        formMessage.save()
        return redirect('/')
    else:
        ticket = Ticket.objects.all()
        mesticket = MessageTicket.objects.all()

        context = {
            'ticket': ticket,
            'message': mesticket,
            'formTicket': formTicket,
            'formMessage': formMessage,
        }
        return render(request, 'support/register.html', context)
```

***Como os dois formulários são renderizados na página html:***

```
{% extends 'support/base.html' %}
{% block title %} Tickets {% endblock %}
{% block content %}
<form method="POST" action="cad">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ formTicket.as_p }}
    {{ formMessage.as_p }}
    <button type="submit">SAVE</button>
</form>
{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depois que você chama a função `form.is_valid()`, você pode acessar/alterar os dados do formulário usando o `form.cleaned_data['campo_do_formulario']`.

Seu código ficaria assim:

```
if formMessage.is_valid():
        
    formMessage.cleaned_data['ticket_id'] = help

    formMessage.save()
    return redirect('/')
```

Você também pode ver a [documentação do Forms API](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/forms/api/#accessing-clean-data).